# Ubuntu Server 16.04 server GUI install apt-get install error

Tags: 16.04

Hi guys im trying to install GUI on Ubuntu server 16.04 but I constantly get an error about a forbidden ip 91.189.88.149 failed to fetch

Answer (score -1):

The servers of the repositories change from time to time.  You can update this information using these two commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

It wouldn't hurt to run it twice.  Sometimes upgrades provide some updated information for locations.  Running it the second time would assure to have the upto minute lastest.  It's very unlikely having some information late by a few days would ever make a difference.

To avoid this, you might consider the two lines part of your routine when performing terminal package installs.

**Check your Repository Download server:**

This information is coming from your download server, which may not be the most upto date.  You can check it with these steps:

Go into **Software and updates** -> (click tab) **Ubuntu Software** -> (click dropdown to select a different **Download from** source).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76548/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-ubuntu-server-16-04-server-gui-install-apt-g).